# illegal start of expression error

Tags: java, error-handling

```
public Properties prop = new Properties();
```

I get an illegal start of expression error when I try this code snippet. I couldnt figure out what was wrong though.

Comment: show more code.  It is the context in which this code resides that will reveal the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably you have used this construction inside of a method or constructor.

"public" keyword is allowed for classes, class fields, and methods, but is not allowed for local variables.

Solution: remove "public" from your `prop` declaration.

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
```

Comment: seems likely.  I'd still like to have the actual code revealed instead of just guessing "maybe it is blam".